# Iphone/iOS Web Browser Debugging

Tags: javascript, ios, debugging, web, browser

does anyone know a tool or trick to debug iOS browser without having an iPhone device. I'm struggling to debug the javascript for that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What platform are you on? If you're on macOS, you can download Xcode, where emulators are built in. And, regardless if Mac or Windows, Firefox and Chrome do offer device preview modes in the developer tools. Chrome may come closer, since it's also a WebKit browser, like Safari, the browser used in iOS.

Comment: thank you, I tried using xcode but it didnt solve the problem, is there any other emulator? some codes don't work properly in Safari or on iPhone devices. this makes me have to review my code but I dont know what code it is